# Ruby on rails3, how to do a select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

There are two tables- 1. merchants and 2.ranking.

- **merchants**- id, merchant_name, date and so on
- **ranking** - id,merchant_id, customer_id and so on (each customers ranking for merchants)

I want to sort merchants details for asending using ranking.

How to write the selection query?

Do I want to use subqueries?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I couldn't get any idea about how to do this, please help me!

Comment: I found the SQl query- select 
 merchant_id,name, COUNT(*) AS no_of_reviews 
from 
 reviews a, merchants b 
where
 a.merchant_id=b.id 
GROUP BY
  merchant_id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(merchant_id) DESC

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
merchants = merchants.includes(:reviews).order("COUNT(reviews.merchant_id) DESC").group("merchant_id")
```